# Should I have a 'dev' branch separate from a 'production' branch?

Tags: git, source-code, workflows

I recently set up my staging and production server environments on Heroku and everything is working great. Through Heroku, you can deploy from a Git branch - e.g. `master` or `my-feature`. This got me thinking - should I have a `dev` branch?

The `dev` branch would essentially function as the *current stage in `development`*; branch `my-feature` would be merged into `dev` once it was completed. I would then deploy `dev` to my *staging* environment and, if everything checks out, I would merge `dev` into `master`, and deploy `master` to *production*.

At first glance, to me this makes sense as a workflow. Looking at the branches, it is immediately evident what is in development and what is in production. With the usual `master` branch being actively developed and deployed, it's difficult to draw the line at a glance without looking at timestamps or SHA commit hashes.

The only downside I can see is that my commit logs would basically have a *merged `dev` with `master`* commit for every deploy to production. Personally I don't see this as a big problem, because it helps in defining the line *what code is production using?*.

**Does having a `dev` branch make sense if it is used in this way?**

PS - I'm working alone on this project. I'm just curious if this makes sense as a general workflow for developers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I feel that this is overkill for a single person working on a single web application.

I would use **tags** to give version numbers to versions you release to the production server. The staging server can just use the latest commit on master, whereas production uses a tag.

Have a "release" script that updates files with the new release number, commits them, then tags the commit with that release number.

Comment: I agree with this. Tags are the built-in way to manage deployments, whereas branches have the full power for concurrent development, and whenever possible, you should not overkill. Just develop on master, you will have everything you need.

Comment: +1. Tags are much simpler to manage than branches, and more than adequate for this job.  The only reason you might need a production branch is if you decide you need to apply hotfixes for bugs in production while working on long-term development tasks, but this is unlikely to crop up for a single developer/small team.  Stay agile by keeping your master branch deployable at all times, is my usual suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is a common workflow. The popular [gitflow workflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) has a separate development branch, for instance.

Different teams uses different workflows. Which stems from different team compositions. Workflows that works for open source project with large number of external contributors may not necessarily work for internal company project or for personal project. There is no one good workflow that works for everybody.